# Swinging, waving, wielding

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

When I looked into my son's room again an hour later, he was still swinging/waving/wielding his plastic pirate sword (around) pretending he was fighting with someone.

1. Which one of "swinging", "waving", and "wielding" sound more wild and aggresive?
2. Which one would be the most common to use?
3. Is it more common to include "around" at the end? Or would it sound like the son is just turning around and around holding the sword?

Comment: Most of them involve threatening rather than using. Swinging is the only one that implies actual battle. You swing a sword at your opponent.

Comment: ...or thrust - depends if you intend to slash or pierce, and what type of sword it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here, "swinging" and "waving" are very similar. Keep in mind that "swinging" can also apply to things that are dangling (swinging back and forth, Tarzan swinging on a vine), and "waving" can apply to waving a flag or waving your hand. So "swinging a sword" is more of a back and forth slashing motion, but "waving" a sword is more like moving it around up in the air. In terms of which one is more aggressive, that's a toss-up. "Swinging" probably means he knows what he is doing and/or he is aiming. "Waving" probably means he is not aiming at something and moving more erratically, but may not cause as much damage. "Wielding" is less wild since it doesn't imply motion. You can wield something by just holding it.
2. Any of them make sense.
3. "Around" is just a preposition that adds meaning. It means he is not swinging the sword over and over like an ax, but instead swinging/waving it all over the place. Swinging/waving around does not mean he is turning in circles. "Wielding around" is never used, since wielding is not a motion.

Comment: I disagree about _wield_. Dictionaries define it as 'Hold _and use_ a tool or weapon' or 'hold it as though about to use it', so it can be aggressive. (We don't say 'wield about' though.)